# How to merge group by last rows based on date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have `files` table with direction of `in` and `out`.

How should I sum data when count of statuses are more than 4 and leave 1st to 4th column intact. For now I use `Having` to filter that data which is not what I want.

When I group by `status` field, the result could have been more than 4 rows with different statuses (when I use year resolution (`%Y`) for instance).

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') start_time, status, count(*) stat_count
FROM files WHERE direction='out' 
AND start_time > '2017-17-01' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d'), status HAVING stat_count>10 ORDER BY start_time, stat_count DESC
```

How should I put count(*) of other data in `other` column?

**EDIT-1:**
This is a sample result:

```
start_time   status         stat_count
2017-05-01   success            23
2017-05-01   failed_permission  14
2017-05-01   failed_io          13
2017-05-01   file_not_found     7
2017-05-01   unknown            2
2017-05-01   large_file         1
2017-05-03   success            23
2017-05-03   failed_permission  14
2017-05-03   failed_io          13
2017-05-03   file_not_found     7
2017-05-03   large_file         1
2017-05-03   exception          1
```

When status count is more than 4 based on date it should have been summed in a column called `other` based on `start_time`:

```
start_time   status         stat_count
2017-05-01   success            23
2017-05-01   failed_permission  14
2017-05-01   failed_io          13
2017-05-01   file_not_found     7
2017-05-01   other              3
2017-05-03   success            23
2017-05-03   failed_permission  14
2017-05-03   failed_io          13
2017-05-03   file_not_found     7
2017-05-03   other              2
```

**NB:** They're not summed based on their values. It is a limitation strictly on count of rows per day. If there is 4 rows with values of 5,4,3,1 they all will be kept as we have not reached 5th row.

Comment: sample data with expected result will be helpful

Comment: @OtoShavadze, thanks could you check the *EDIT-1* part.

Comment: It looks like you want to report, for each distinct day, up to four most numerous `status` values and their counts. Is that correct? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @O.Jones, yes that's it.